# Android toggle button just working once. How can i make it work every time?

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm learning android and i'm working on a really simple task. I'm using a Toggle Button to show/hide a password, when i start the application and click on the Toggle Button, it works perfectly... the first time.

But when i click on it again (to hide or show the password again). does not happen anything. I hope someone can help me, i would appreciate it so much. Here it's my code, by the way, if you want to check it out.

```
package com.Amet.Android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Texting extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    Button checked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bChecked);
    final ToggleButton tgShow = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbType);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordField);
    TextView invalid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInvalid);

    tgShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tgShow.isSelected()){

                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }else{

                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
}



}
```

Also i tried replacing the:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

within the "if" statement with this:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

but i've got the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tgShow.isChecked() instead of tgShow.isSelected()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `EditText` when `setInputType` is called reset `TransformationMethod` to `null`. This code works for me:

```
mPasswordField = (EditText)customView.findViewById(R.id.password);
...
private void showPassword(boolean show) {
    int selectionStart = mPasswordField.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = mPasswordField.getSelectionEnd();
    mPasswordField.setInputType(show ?
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD :
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    mPasswordField.setTransformationMethod(show ?
        null :
        PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    mPasswordField.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}
```

According to [this thread](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/229168-how-to-set-the-edittext-password-to-hidden/) one even dont have to call `setInputMethod`